# How to exclude and filter few columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know we can select only few columns using pandas dataframe filter, but can we also exclude only some columns?

Here is MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'num_1': [10,20,30], 'num_2': [20,30,40]})

df.filter(regex='num')
```

Can we select all columns not having 'num' in the columns:

Something like:

```
df.filter(regex='^(num)')
```

**Required Output**

```
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

**Note**

```
# these already works, i am only looking regex way
df[['id']] # gives the required output
```

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: `regex='^((?!num).)*$'` (or perhaps `'^(?!num).*$'`)?, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word,=. IMO, that's not very readable and really hard to know how it will break, so I'd stick with `str.contains`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using contains**

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('num')]
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith('num')]
```

**Using difference**

```py
df[df.columns.difference(['num_1','num_2'])]
df[df.columns.difference([i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('num'])]
df[df.columns.difference([i for i in df.columns if 'num' in i]
```

**Using drop**

```py
df[df.columns.drop(['num_1','num_2'])] # do not use axis=1 here.
df[df.columns.drop([i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('num'])]
df[df.columns.drop([i for i in df.columns if 'num' in i]
```

**Credits to @ALollz**
If you insist on using `filter`:

```
df.filter(regex='^((?!num).)*$')
```

But this is not only ugly and difficult to read/understand but also vulnerable to some pitfalls of regex search as discussed in [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word,=) .

I would suggest to stick with `contains`.

Comment: how can you method chain this approach without using filter though?

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of columns not having `num` using list comprehension

```
cols_without_num = [x for x in list(df) if 'num' not in x]
```

Then subset the data

```
df[cols_without_num]
```